How to set schemaLocation in wsdl from external library
I have application which had few modules, one of them has schemas xsd. I have webservices and in my xsd and wsdl files I had schemaLocation refer to this module. Now I have one module and another modules I have in external libraries(this module with schemas too).
How can I set schemaLocation from external library?
I have task wsdl-to-java and I need to have class generated from wsdl to java but I have error with schema location because now I have this schemas in external libraries.
